# Using an Environment Variable to get the Value of Another Environment Variable

Tags: yaml, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Using Bitbucket Pipelines and I have Repository Variables (not Deployment Variables) like so:

`DEV_DB_SERVER`

`QA_DB_SERVER`

`STG_DB_SERVER`

At this stage in my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` script, I cannot leverage the Deployment variables - since you can only expose them in a single step, I am trying to substitute the first portion of the Repository vars doing something like this:

`echo ${"${ENV}_DB_SERVER"}` which would output the actual server address for each environment - depending on the environment being targeted: $ENV.  Incidentally, the above syntax produces: `bash: DB_SERVER=${"$ENV_DB_SERVER"}: bad substitution` but I have tried myriad variations without success.

I am trying to avoid using gigantic `switch` or `if` statements and spelling out every variable distinctly. Anyone know if something like this is possible and how it can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not exactly what I was after, I *was* able to achieve my goal with a one-liner per environment variable, which is much better than mentioning each (27 ea.) discretely for each of our 4 environments:

```
- tmp="${ENV}_DB_SERVER" && export DB_SERVER=${!tmp}
```

There may be a more elegant way to accomplish this, and I'd love your feedback if you know of one, but this works for now.